# Is TCP connect restricted in local area network?

Tags: networking, tcp, gateway

1. a server IP is 151.101.129.69
2. my home PC IP is 192.168.0.1, my office PC IP is also 192.168.0.1, but of course these 2 PCs are in different locations.

If both of my PCs are connecting to server port 80, it has to be 2 TCP connections.
We know that a TCP connect is composed by 4 parts, source IP/port and target IP/port, so it must NOT be like this at the same time (very coincidently both clients start the connect with port 12345):

1. my home PC connect: 192.168.0.1:12345 <-> 151.101.129.69:80
2. my office PC connect: 192.168.0.1:12345 <-> 151.101.129.69:80

My guess is, every TCP connect in the world actually does not connect across gateways, it's more like:

192.168.0.1:12345(homePC) <-> 41.100.90.2:33333(homeRouter) <-> 151.0.1.1:44444(someKindOfPublicGateway) <-> 151.101.129.69:80(server)
the example above shows there're 3 TCP connections actually, while it might be for my office PC like this at the same time:
192.168.0.1:12345(officePC) <-> 10.132.10.88:55555(officeRouter) <-> 133.10.100.1:44444(officeNetworkGateway) <-> 140.144.10.1:54321(someKindOfPublicGateway) <-> 151.101.129.69:80(server)

so it's actually different public gateway ip/port connecting to the server.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2):

> My guess is, every TCP connect in the world actually does not connect across gateways

What you describe is [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation), i.e rewriting of source IP and port by gateways. This is not a requirement for TCP. The requirement for TCP is that there is a network route between client and server, i.e. server can be reached by the client and client can be reached by the server.

With [private IP addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) like 192.168.0.1 though it is not possible to have such a network route to some host on the internet, since private IP addresses are per definition not routable in the public internet. That's why some kind of translation into public routable IP is needed and NAT provides this.

For TCP connections between systems on the public internet or systems inside the same private LAN such translation isn't necessary though. Thus no gateways are needed here. Note that systems on the public internet are not only servers. Instead many institutions have public IP addresses for their clients too. NAT is mainly used to address the shortage of IPv4 addresses, i.e. used for residential access, closed company networks or in mobile networks. With IPv6 such shortage is no longer a problem and some networks use private IPv4 addresses (requiring NAT) and public IPv6 (no NAT needed) in the same network.

Comment: @DanielFarrell: Port mapping affects the TCP layer. There are no such things as ports at the IP layer.